# ubuntu htop half of cores in blue 100%

Tags: ubuntu, htop

I had try to reboot my server with two e5-2637v3 cpu.
does blue mean nothing to do?

[image: htop snapshot]

Comment: We need much more information about the version, running applications, etc.

Comment: Blue is often kernel tasks.  Do you have some kind of raid rebuild, zfs scrub or something going or something else that might be sucking up I/O?  I'd probably look at something like iotop, to see if you have some kind of heavy I/O going.